# non unitary representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, unitary-representations

A paper by M.L. [Whippman](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0034487774900184) in Rep. Math. Phys. 5 (1974), 81, mentions at the bottom of the second page ''the possible occurrence of non-unitary representations that arise when reducing a direct product of representations of a non-compact group''. I'd like to see a simple example of this situation. The context is unitary representations, but it seems to me that the direct product of unitary representations cannot lead to this.

Comment: What is a direct product of unitary representations?

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle: The canonical representation on the tensor product of the two representation spaces.